# Cannot access Amazon RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created a free-tier PostgreSQL RDS instance and everything appears to looks good on the portal. However, I am unable to get to the instance.

[image]

[image]

Going through the troubleshooting steps, they mention it could a firewall issue on my end. However, a quick ping from [an external site](http://network-tools.com/) reveals the same timeout issue.

Is there a step that I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ping is typically disabled** in AWS Security Groups. It is not recommended as a method of checking network connections.

The best method would be to use an **SQL client** to connect to the database via JDBC or ODBC.

Things to check:

- Your RDS instance was launched as **Publicly Accessible**
- Your RDS instance was launched in a **Public Subnet** (Definition: The subnet's Route Table points to an Internet Gateway)
- The **Security Group** permits connections on the database port (this is also where you could permit PING access, but no guarantee that it would work with an RDS instance)

Comment: Good to know about ping being disabled (fyi, telnet did work). For me, the problem was solved by adding an inbound rule to the security group to allow my specific IP to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the associated Security Groups that you have tagged. Security groups hold the firewall rules. Either you may have to tweak the group that you have selected or try changing / modifying the group that you (or your profile) have access to.